# Minimum remainder in range of multiple of integer for an integer

Tags: math, excel-formula

Is it possible to resolve below given problem with excel formula?

One machine can produce in lot ( range of integer between two numbers)
For example, it can produce in multiple of 5 to 7 batches per lot ( can produce in multiple of 5,6 & 7 ). I have one order of 8 batches , now I want to compute that how many MINIMUM extra batches needs to be produce to fulfill the lot size requirement.
Answer for this question is = 2 ( I can produce 5+5=10 ( 8 order + 2 extra ).

| Variable value | Variable value | Variable value | Want formula to calculate this | For ref |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Min capability | Max capability | Order | Extra batch to fulfill order | Lot combi |
| 5 | 7 | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 | 6 | 0 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 | 7 | 0 | 7 |
| 5 | 7 | 8 | 2 | 5+5 |
| 5 | 7 | 9 | 1 | 5+5 |
| 5 | 7 | 10 | 0 | 5+5 |
| 5 | 7 | 11 | 0 | 5+6 |
| 5 | 7 | 12 | 0 | 5+7 |
| 5 | 7 | 13 | 0 | 6+7 |
| 5 | 7 | 14 | 0 | 7+7 |
| 5 | 7 | 15 | 0 | 5+5+5 |
| 5 | 7 | 16 | 0 | 5+5+6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: If you're asked for 16, can't you do 5+5+6? Rather than "5+6+7, oops, I have 2 extra"

Comment: yes , correct , my mistake , we can do 5+5+6 , without any extra plate

Comment: so the Extra batch to fulfill order will be zero

Comment: I corrected the question & table accordingly

Comment: This is a non-problem for any order size of 10 or more.  Any number greater than 9 can be rewritten as the sum of a suitable number of 5s, 6s, 7s. I wouldn't bother looking for a formula for the integers 1..9 I'd just write them into the table.

Comment: When the order n is greater than 10, write the euclidean division of n by 5: n = 5 q + r. If r = 0 pick q batches of 5. If r = 1, then n = 5q+1 = 5(q-1) + 6. If r = 2, then n = 5q+2 = 5(q-1)+7. If r = 3, then n = 5q+3 = 5(q-2) + 6 + 7. If r = 4, then n = 5q+4 = 5(q-2)+7x2.

Comment: Dear  High Performance Mark, 5 to 7 is an example , basically it is variable value. For example min/max capability is 3 & 3 than answer will be different , I think that we can not create master table for "extra batch to fulfill order".

Comment: I think if you study @Stef's comment carefully you'll be able to find the formula you seek.